# Arduino leonardo infinite uploading on windows 10

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to build a midi controller using an Adafruit Trellis and an arduino leonardo. When it comes to run the code, the uploading status freezes and doesn't complete. I've tried to run a hello world using both an arduinoleonardo and a uno but I still had the same problem. I've deleted the IDE, reinstalled it but nothing has changed. I think it's a driver problem but I actually don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Uno is good (no defect), try to plug into a different USB port and try different COM #. Also make sure that you are selecting the correct type of Arduino.